# How to sum up values with other specific element in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a transcript.xml like this and want to calculate the gpa

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transcript>
    <courses>
        <course>
            <code>IK2210</code>        
            <credits>3</credits>
            <grade>A</grade>
        </course>
        <course>
            <code>IB2210</code>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <grade>A</grade>
        </course>
        <course>
            <code>IB2210</code>
            <credits>1</credits>
            <grade>C</grade>
        </course>
        <course>
            <code>ID1234</code>
            <credits>2</credits>
            <grade>B</grade>
        </course>
    </courses>

</transcript>
```

I imported the transcript like this

```
<xsl:variable name="transcript" select="document('transcript2.xml')/transcript"/>
```

I tried to do this

```
<xsl:value-of select=" (4*(sum($transcript/courses/course/credits[$transcript/courses/course/grade='A'])) + 3*(sum($transcript/courses/course/credits[$transcript/courses/course/grade='B'])) + 2*(sum($transcript/courses/course/credits[$transcript/courses/course/grade='C'])) + 1*(sum($transcript/courses/course/credits[$transcript/courses/course/grade='D']))) div (sum($transcript/courses/course/credits))"/>
```

but the parts

```
(sum($transcript/courses/course/credits[$transcript/courses/course/grade='A']))
```

sum up all the credits

How can check the condition?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your formula would have worked if instead of using:

```
(sum($transcript/courses/course/credits[$transcript/courses/course/grade='A']))
```

You used:

```
(sum($transcript/courses/course[grade='A']/credits))
```

but perhaps this is a bit more concise:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="kGrade" match="credits" use="../grade"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:variable name="transcript" select="document('SOTranscript.xml')/transcript" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$transcript" mode="getTotal" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="transcript" mode="getTotal">
    <xsl:value-of
            select="(4 * sum(key('kGrade', 'A')) + 
                  3 * sum(key('kGrade', 'B')) + 
                  2 * sum(key('kGrade', 'C')) + 
                  sum(key('kGrade', 'D'))
                 ) div sum(courses/course/credits)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When used on your sample input, the result is:

```
<root>3.5555555555555553</root>
```

which I believe is the expected value.

Comment: the second line works! However, the kGrade also gives me the "9" which is the sum of the credits from all the course

Comment: Did you do something differently from my example?  When I try `<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kGrade', 'A'))"/>`, I get 6, and `<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kGrade', 'B'))"/>` produces 2, as expected.

Comment: I guess it maybe the problem of the path. I import the xml and use the $transcript. Will it affect?

Comment: Do you mean you're using the `document()` function?  If so, I think you need to use something like the above, so you are in the context of the imported DOM.